# Showing that $S$ is a basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a finite set in a vector space $V$ with the property that every **x** in $V$ has a unique representation as a linear combination of elements of $S$. Show that $S$ is a basis of $V$.

---

My approach:

Since every **x** in $V$ has a unique representation as a linear combination of elements in $S$, this implies that the matrix formed by the columns of $S$ contain a pivot in every column, and thus has no free variable, so the vectors in $S$ are linearly independent.

Since every **x** in V has a representation as a linear combination of $S$, it follows that $S$ spans $V$.

So $S$ is linearly independent and spans $V$, so $S$ is a basis of $V$.

Comment: What is the "matrix formed by the columns of $S$"? For example, if $V$ is the vector space of real polynomials of degree at most one and $S = \{3x - 7, 2x + 1\}$, what is the matrix you are referring to?

Comment: Not really understanding your proof of independence. It is easier: If $S = \{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and if $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i = 0$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i = \sum_{i=1}^n 0\cdot v_i$, so by uniqueness of the representation, $c_i=0$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$, proving independence.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I have not learned how to deal with those vector spaces yet. So I am assuming this doesn't make sense if V is the vector space of real polynomials?

Comment: Yes. Your proof only makes sense for $\mathbb{R}^n$, but most vector spaces are not $\mathbb{R}^n$ so you need a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $S$ spans $V$ because every $x\in V$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $S$. So we show that the set is linearly independent.

Suppose we have, for $x\in V$, $x=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_nv_n$, for $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and where $v_i$ are the elements of $V$. Suppose we then have,

$$x=b_1v_1+b_2v_2+\dots+b_nv_n$$

because $x$ is a unique linear combination, we have $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$. Then

$$(a_1-b_1)v_1+\dots+(a_n-b_n)v_n=0$$

But, $a_i=b_i\implies a_i-b_i=0$, so we have the coefficient of each $v_i$ equal to $0$. This is the definition of linear independence.

Then we have shown the set $S$ is linearly independent, and spans $V$. So it is a basis.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly $S$ spans $V$ so that's easy enough. Now consider $S=\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ Then since

$$v_i=1\cdot v_1+0\cdot\sum_{n\ne i} v_n$$

we see that the $v_i$ are linearly independent since the expression above is **unique**, so there are no other ways to express $v_i$. Hence $S$ is a basis.